# Static Niagara System for fire on a torch

Tags: unreal, particles, unreal-5

I'm building a Niagara System for fire and smoke that would be placed on a torch when it's lit. While smoke works just fine when it's static, when I move the camera (and so the torch itself moves too) the smoke is always far behind the torch. I understand it makes sense from physics perspective, but for the purpose of my game I need the smoke to be static on top of the torch, so I want all particles to always be vertically above the torch.

Is there a way to turn off inertia (for lack of a better term) on particles? Or probably I should use another approach for my problem?

Comment: In Unity this would be done by changing the "Simulation Space" on the particle system to "Local" instead of "World" — is there a similar setting in Niagara? You may also want to consider [using a ribbon of geometry rather than discrete particles](https://twitter.com/Ed_dV/status/1209356023774900225) — this can let you get [fluid swaying of the flame/smoke when the torch is in motion](https://twitter.com/Ed_dV/status/816088833028558848), without high overdraw costs from tonnes of particles.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, one checkbox fixed the problem. Guess I couldn't properly formulate my question to google. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With a suggestion from @dmgregory I found a solution: Local Space makes particles relative to the emitter origin. It is located under Niagara Overview Node's properties -> Emitter > Local Space.

[image]